# How to open xls file in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, xls

I want to devlop an application in iphone where user can open a xls file ,Can do some editing on data already present and finally save it.

How can i do it any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIWebView` to view an XLS file, but you won't be able to edit it. There's nothing built in to the iPhone SDK that will do this for you. You could try contacting [these folks](http://www.quickoffice.com/quicksheet_iphone/) to see if they would license their software to you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Hardik it is very simple if you want to open a local xls file.

1. Add a local xls file in to your project
2. Drag and drop an UIWebView control on the view.
3. Connect Files owner and UIWebView Object
4. Add this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Get the path where your local xls file is located
    NSString *FilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"xls"];

    //Now To use a local resource file in a web view you need to use NSURL fileURLWithPath:
    NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:FilePath];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [m_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Now just Build and Go